# Splitting column with key/value pairs into separate columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm dealing with some dense genetic data and the input file (100GB) has a particular column that has a bunch of key/value pairs. One example value of this column would be:

```
RS=1227143127;dbSNPBuildID=151;SSR=0;GENEINFO=ZKSCAN7:55888;VC=SNV;INT;R3;GNO;FREQ=GnomAD:0.9999,8.067e-05|TOPMED:0.9999,5.575e-05|dbGaP_PopFreq:1,0
```

It's *mostly* key/value, except you can see a few do not have a value (e.g. `R3`). Additionally, not every column has the key/values in the same order, nor do they have the same key/value pairs. This is a large set of public genomics data, so there's not much I can do to change the input, so I'm curious if there's a good way to split this out that handles the oddities above.

At the *very least*, I'm looking for a way to split out the "GENEINFO" and "VC" into separate columns. I'm assuming I'd use `withColumn` somehow, but not sure how exactly. Perhaps something like this:

```
spark.read
  .option("delimiter", "\t")
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv("/home/depressio/spark-vcf/GCF_000001405.25.tsv") // the big input file
  .withColumn("VC", col("INFO").???)
  .withColumn("GENEINFO", col("INFO").???)
```

Not sure exactly how to pluck that data out. If I have the column value itself as a String, I can do:

```
info.split("=|;").grouped(2).filter(_.length > 1).map { case Array(k, v) => k -> v }.toMap.getOrElse("VC", "")
```

Lengthy but deterministic, I guess? Still, not sure how to incorporate that in `withColumn`.

Comment: You can turn the code in your second example into a Spark [UDF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-scalar.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can split the data and `explode` it for getting Key and Value. Below logic only considers the `GENEINFO` and `VC` as you mentioned in the problem statement. But if you need to add any more Key and Value then you can change the `isin(....)` condition and add your Key.

```
 scala> df.show(truncate=False)
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Info                                                                                            |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|RS=1227143127;dbSNPBuildID=151;SSR=0;GENEINFO=ZKSCAN7:55888;VC=SNV;INT;R3;GNO;FREQ=GnomAD:0.9999|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

scala> val df1 =  df.withColumn("Temp", split(col("Info"), ";")).withColumn("Temp" ,explode(col("Temp"))).withColumn("TempKey", split(col("Temp"), "=")(0)).withColumn("TempValue", split(col("Temp"), "=")(1)).filter(col("TempKey").isin("GENEINFO", "VC")).drop("Temp")
scala> val df2  = df1.groupBy(col("Info")).pivot("TempKey").agg(concat_ws(",", collect_list(col("TempValue"))))
scala> df2.show()
+--------------------+-------------+---+
|               Info |     GENEINFO| VC|
+--------------------+-------------+---+
|RS=1227143127;dbS...|ZKSCAN7:55888|SNV|
+--------------------+-------------+---+
```